# Data exchange formatting between client and server

Tags: python, sockets, networking, server, client

I'm writing a Bank program in Python that utilizes client/server communication. From what I understand, data is transferred over sockets in raw bytes.

That means the client and server should have mutual understanding of the data that is passed between each other so they can decode it appropriately? How do ATMs around the world transfer data back and forth between Bank servers?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_teller_machine)

> Common application layer transaction protocols, such as Diebold 91x
>   (911 or 912) and NCR NDC or NDC+ provide emulation of older
>   generations of hardware on newer platforms with incremental extensions
>   made over time to address new capabilities, although companies like
>   NCR continuously improve these protocols issuing newer versions (e.g.
>   NCR's AANDC v3.x.y, where x.y are subversions). Most major ATM
>   manufacturers provide software packages that implement these
>   protocols. Newer protocols such as IFX have yet to find wide
>   acceptance by transaction processors.[62]